# Windows XP machine has no IP address until a user logs in

Tags: windows-xp, networking, remote-desktop

We have a few Windows XP machines in our office which we RDP into. When a machine reboots, the machine does not have an IP address assigned, well not that is visible to the rest of the network. It does not show up in Network browsing, respond to pings (trying to get ip address via nmblookup or mdns, for example).

However, the moment a user logs in to the machine at its console, it gets an IP address (before the windows desktop is even shown), and from that point on, can be fully operated over the network (RDP, file sharing, etc).

It's not critical, except for after a power outage or reboot when the machine needs to be accessed from outside the office.

Is this a known problem? Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: You can check if its connected then by setting logon.src to cmd.exe (copy and rename) and then when it goes to a screensaver in the logon screen, type ipconfig

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking that a software firewall may be in the way, and that group policy may be in play too.

Run rsop.msc then check Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Network>Network Connections>Windows Firewall to see what settings are being pulled down.

It might just be cutting off all connectivity until the firewall expressly allows it once it is running.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a fixed IP address to the network adapter and also put in the DNS server it works.
Windows XP has an IP address before log ins.